# main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused magento2

Tags: magento2

Getting this error in live site kindly help me

```
[2020-06-05 05:18:27] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused {"report_id":"e873ea2faa3854c65aa211c09b211758e5c754902980db29df10cf09aafa8ec5","exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []
```

getting this error so many times in log kindly help me how to fix this 
already tried env.php fix localhost to 127.0.0.1
but still not able to fix

Comment: Can you check if the database is running and the credentials are correct? Are you able to connect from the shell using the same credentials? Try to connect via command `mysql -h hostname -u username -p databasename`

Comment: everything is working as expected even the website is live and running